# Cannot remove DataRow from DataTable

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite, mvvm-light

I'm trying to list all tables from my SQLite database, but I only need the normal tables and not the system tables. I tried this using a foreach and removing the row while looping, but I get an exception. Can anyone please point out what I'm doing wrong here because I don't really see where I'm going wrong.

My only thought is that I can't remove from the DataTable while looping, but I don't know how I would approach this problem otherwise.

Database currently contains 4 tables, 3 normal and 1 system table

Code:

```
        SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=db.sqlite");

        connection.Open();

        DbTables = connection.GetSchema("Tables");

        foreach (DataRow row in DbTables.Rows)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(row[3].ToString());

            if (row[3].ToString() == "SYSTEM_TABLE")
                DbTables.Rows.Remove(row);
        }

        connection.Close();
```

Exception:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 17 : Cannot get 'Main' value (type 'MainViewModel') from '' (type 'ViewModelLocator'). BindingExpression:Path=Main; DataItem='ViewModelLocator' (HashCode=65325907); target element is 'MainWindow' (Name=''); target property is 'DataContext' (type 'Object') TargetInvocationException:'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Property accessor 'Main' on object 'DatabaseExplorer.ViewModel.ViewModelLocator' threw the following exception:'Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.' ---> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified; enumeration operation might not execute.
   at System.Data.RBTree`1.RBTreeEnumerator.MoveNext()
   at DatabaseExplorer.ViewModel.MainViewModel..ctor(IDataService dataService) in Project\ViewModel\MainViewModel.cs:line 61
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Reflection.ConstructorInfo.Invoke(Object[] parameters)
   at GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Ioc.SimpleIoc.MakeInstance[TClass]()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeImpl(Object[] args)
   at System.Delegate.DynamicInvoke(Object[] args)
   at GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Ioc.SimpleIoc.DoGetService(Type serviceType, String key)
   at GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Ioc.SimpleIoc.GetInstance[TService]()
   at DatabaseExplorer.ViewModel.ViewModelLocator.get_Main() in Project\ViewModel\ViewModelLocator.cs:line 54
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.ComponentModel.ReflectPropertyDescriptor.GetValue(Object component)
   at MS.Internal.Data.ValueTable.GetValue(Object item, PropertyDescriptor pd, Boolean indexerIsNext)
   at MS.Internal.Data.PropertyPathWorker.GetValue(Object item, Int32 level)
   at MS.Internal.Data.PropertyPathWorker.RawValue(Int32 k)'
```

Console output when I remove the if clause:

```
SYSTEM_TABLE
table
table
table
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not modify collection while enumerating it. So either you may change your `foreach` loop into `for` or create temporary collection that will be filled with rows to be removed and remove them afterwards.

First approach (need testing, I'm not before my computer right now):

```
for (int i = DbTables.Rows.Count; i >=0 ; i--)
{
    if (DbTables.Rows[i].ToString() == "SYSTEM_TABLE")
         DbTables.Rows.RemoveAt(i);
}
```

Second approach:

```
DbTables = connection.GetSchema("Tables");

var rowsToBeRemoved = new List<DataRow>();

foreach (DataRow row in DbTables.Rows)
{
    Console.WriteLine(row[3].ToString());

    if (row[3].ToString() == "SYSTEM_TABLE")
       rowsToBeRemoved.Add(row);
}

foreach DataRow row in rowsToBeRemoved)
{
    DbTables.Rows.Remove(row);
}
```

Comment: Yeah you're completely right, and right after I read this I remember I only need the table names so there's no real need for me to remove them, I should just store the normal tables in a List.. Sorry for wasting your time, but thanks anyways for your help! It's much appreciated!

Comment: No problem, always glad to help even a little bit :)